# Difference Between Mean, Average, Expected Value for Calculus

Tags: calculus, probability

Lately, I am having trouble understanding the difference between what is average, what is expected value, and what is mean when using Calculus. I am under the impression now that they are the same thing which confuses me. Why would expected value, the $E[X]$ symbol, have the form $E[X]=\int_a^bx\cdot f(x)dx$, rather than $E[X]=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx$. I thought the second equation was the definition of average from a calculus stand point. I am wanting to know the difference between using these three terms and when to use their corresponding equations appropriately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between average and expected value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904343/what-is-the-difference-between-average-and-expected-value)  As noted in the answers to that question, the "mean" and "expected value" are basically the same.  "Average" is a bit dicey, however---an average is a measure of central tendency, and so the mode and median are also averages.  It is likely best not to use the word unless you are being intentionally informal or are providing more context.

Comment: @XanderHenderson That helps me from a non-calculus standpoint. I will rephrase the question. I am wanting it to be for calculus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between statistical mean and calculus mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538553/what-is-the-difference-between-statistical-mean-and-calculus-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\int_a^b f(x) dx=1$$ so
$$
\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx=\frac{1}{b-a}
$$
is in some sense "an average probability used" (see example below).

You want to say that expectation is the *weighted* average of value points, where the weights are given by the distribution, so this is like finding a center of mass, with density given by $f(x)$, and the result is exactly
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{\int_a^b x f(x) dx}{\int_a^b f(x) dx} = \int_a^b x f(x) dx
$$
because the integral in the denominator is 1.

**Example**

It is like, if I have 0.1 kg at -1, 0.8 kg at 0, and 0.1 kg at 1, you see the average (center of mass) should be at 0 by symmetry, but your suggestion would give an *average weight* of
$$
\frac{0.1+0.8+0.1}{1 - (-1)} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

But the expected value is not the average weight used, but the location of the center of mass, here
$$
(-1) \cdot 0.1 + 0 \cdot 0.8 + 1 \cdot 0.1 = 0,
$$
as intuitively expected by symmetry.

Comment: So I could use the phrase "weighted average", "average probability", and "expected value" interchangeably. Then, I could use "mean" and "average" interchangeably. Is that correct? I knew center of mass was going to be brought up here which you explained very well.

Comment: I am just going to call expected value a weighted average. Thank you for your help!